# Did "The Cosmic Race" inform "The Anthropophagic Manifesto"?

Tags: cultural-history, art, philosophy, writing, race

José Vasconcelos published [*The Cosmic Race*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_raza_c%C3%B3smica) in 1925. In his view Mexico could construct a new, better race from the diverse origins of its people.

Oswald de Andrade published his [*Anthropophagic Manifesto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifesto_Antrop%C3%B3fago) in 1928. In his view Brazil could construct new, better works by adapting ideas from the exterior. Among Andrade's inspirations was André Breton (perhaps the [*Surrealist Manifesto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrealist_Manifesto) of 1924).

The "Anthropophagic Manifesto" could have been written with "The Cosmic Race" in mind. **Had Andrade read the work of Vasconcelos?**

Comment: If Andrade explicitly mentions having read Vasconcelos, this could be easy to prove otherwise it can only be a matter of opinion either way.

Comment: @KillingTime Whether Vasconcelos's work was distributed in Brazil, what was in Andrade's library, and whether another of his known sources covers the same ground, are not matters of opinion.

Comment: Always hard to prove a negative, but I've searched enough that I'm convinced personally that the answer is no. The parallels between these works seem to be widely recognized, but I can't find any scholar pointing out any evidence that Vasconcelos had any direct influence on de Andrade (or other Brazilians) in the 1920s.